# Auto input value when multiple conditions are fulfilled

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, auto-update, nested-if

i am looking for formula, which can auto detect value in column A & B inputted manually and auto update value in column C once condition is triggered. Thank you.
the example excel: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJB6kSUnWnmxJ7VB0lAO_K88eWg8aZAaLN2KPx0uj14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,IF((A2:A=1)*(B2:B=1), 1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to click on the check mark to accept answer before. Thanks again, @player0